# How to disable logging from a given module on linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, logging, syslog

I have some issue on my Ubuntu 20.4 system where the `mceusb` module is filling up the `kern.log` and `syslog` file with messages like:

```
mceusb 2-2:1.0: Error: urb status = -71/d
```

This completely filled up my entire drive preventing the system from booting up correctly.

How can I turn off logging from just a single module like `mceusb` to prevent it from filling up the drive?

Comment: Look at some of [the advice found here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2406882).

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I had seen that already. However, my receiver seems to work just fine, so instead of trying to replace it, I would just like to keep it from being logged.  Also a solution like this could get generally applied from any 'rogue' logging going on.